# Why is my loop going to the else condition when nothing is entered?

Tags: java, loops, try-catch, java.util.scanner, do-while

Good evening,

I'm at a loss as to why this loop isn't working at all. It's ruining my entire application. below is the code:

```
    System.out.println("Please tell me what to count till?");
    do  
    {
        try
        {
            newEndingValue= input.nextInt();
            if(newEndingValue >= 0 || newEndingValue <= 0) 
            {
               break; //breaks the loop
            }
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("My Apologies, but COMMAND NOT RECOGNIZED!" + "\nPlease tell me what to count till?");
            input.next();       

        }           
    }   
    while(!input.hasNextInt()); 

    v.setEndingValue(newEndingValue);


System.out.println("Please tell me what to count from?");
if(increasingOrDecreasing.equalsIgnoreCase("Increasing")|| increasingOrDecreasing.equals("++") || increasingOrDecreasing.equals("+"))
    {
    do  
    {
      try 
      {
            newInitialValue = input.nextInt();
            if(newInitialValue < v.getEndingValue()) 
                {
                 break; 
                }
            else{ 
                System.out.println("My Apologies, but starting point value must be smaller than ending point value!" + "\nPlease tell me what to count from?"); 
                newInitialValue = (v.getEndingValue()+10);//overrides the value to something that forces the loop back
                }
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) 
            {
            System.out.println("My Apologies, but COMMAND NOT RECOGNIZED!" + "\nPlease tell me what to count from?"); 
            input.next();       
            }           
     }  
    while(!input.hasNextInt() || newInitialValue > v.getEndingValue());
     }
else
{
    do 
    {
    try 
        {
        newInitialValue = input.nextInt();
        if(newInitialValue > v.getEndingValue()) 
            {
             break; //breaks the loop
            }
        else{ 
            System.out.println("My Apologies, but starting point value must be larger than ending point value!" + "\nPlease tell me what to count from?"); 
            newInitialValue = (v.getEndingValue()-10);//overrides the value something that forces the loop back
            }
        }
    catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
        System.out.println("My Apologies, but COMMAND NOT RECOGNIZED!" + "\nPlease tell me what to count from?"); 
        input.next(); //consumes the erroneously typed string value 
        newInitialValue = (v.getEndingValue()-10);
        }           
    }   
    while(!input.hasNextInt() || newInitialValue < v.getEndingValue());
    }
```

So the output is when entered a no, and then 1000 as follows:

Please tell me what to count till?

no

My Apologies, but COMMAND NOT RECOGNIZED!

Please tell me what to count till?

1000

Please tell me what to count from?

My Apologies, but starting point value must be smaller than ending point value!

Please tell me what to count from?

Why is it going straight to the second written else statement? 
Why is it skipping user entry for newInitialValue? 
Please note that if edit code after ending value block to below after entering a string for newEndingValue and then correctly enter a number, this rids me of my error but generates another one if ran again and the user cooperates:

```
...
newInitialValue = input.nextInt(); //essentially gets skipped over by compiler only when previous catch statement is triggered
System.out.println("Please tell me what to count from?");
if(increasingOrDecreasing.equalsIgnoreCase("Increasing")|| increasingOrDecreasing.equals("++") || increasingOrDecreasing.equals("+"))
{...
```

additionally since its printing out "but starting point value must be smaller than ending point value" we can deduce its working with if(incre...) loop and the do and try loops respectively. But its skipping the (newI... = input...)  and the  if(newIntia...) lines of code. i know this cause even manually entering in newInitialValue = 2 (within paramenter) it still goes to this else clause.

Comment: Your code isn't making any sense, could you point out at which point the logic is falling to the `else` block?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and see how the code flows.

Comment: when i ran it without any need for the catch commands it worked out fine. something about the catch when looped works for that value, but then the next block of code is screwed up.

Comment: `if(newEndingValue >= 0 || newEndingValue <= 0)` that's nice

Comment: You will have better luck getting help if you make it easier for people to look at the issue. F.ex.: Make sure that all that code you posted is necessary and if there are irrelevant parts cut them out. Make your indentation make some sense, like don't have an opening bracket more indented than the statements inside it. Say explicitly which one is the `else` you are talking about. Say what is the value of the variables involved in the condition of the corresponding `if`. Chances are that while you do so you will figure out what's the problem.

Comment: i realize i should stream line it but this issue is messing up 400 lines of code and is the same issue multiple times. and i am under a time crunch :C

Comment: I understand. Good luck.

Comment: well i slimmed it down a whole bunch. but i'm not exactly getting any where quickly. is it better more understandable?

Comment: Did you mind @Gabriel's comment at all ? For sure that line is very wrong. In which cases do you expect that condition to be false ? About your `else` problem, what is the value of the variables involved in the condition of the corresponding if ?

Comment: if the condition is a string. it must be a number essentially. and on further inspection i noticed the program works fine if the user cooperates. if they enter a string instead of a number it successfully catches the error, but generates another one. IF i have before the the next desired input     desiredInput =input.nextInt(), it'll consume that one and correctly move on... but this screws up the program if ran again and the user enters correctly.

Comment: When execution jumps to an `else` branch, it can only be because the condition in the corresponding `if` is false. So, last attempt: what is the value of the variables involved in the condition of the `if` corresponding to the problematic `else` ? Also (last attempt as well): in which cases do you expect `if(newEndingValue >= 0 || newEndingValue <= 0)` to evaluate to `false` ?

Comment: well in this case i think the compiler is not even checking the user input. its skipping over it if a catch block is triggered. but its deeper than that... see its successfully  catching, then going to the next series, its clearly going through the if statement for increasing or decreasing, then its going to the try, then is ignoring the input assignment and initiating the if-else loop under it... BUT heres the mystery all values are assigned already as a placeholder and thus it should CONTINUE if its skipping the user assignment, instead its going to the else block only!

Comment: Wrong answers, I give up.

Comment: okay, lets look at this another way: we know if we put an extra user input before the next block it fixes the issue, but screws up if the user is on point... is there a way to make a work around that only spits out a user prompt if a catch had occurred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-_- So the issue is within the while statements:

```
while(!input.hasNextint())
```

this looks ahead and checks the next user input, but since the catch consumed one it looks to the next next and it gets murky... essentially if i don't use this it works.
instead i used:

```
while(isError == true)
```

and under the do loop with the nested if statement i have:

```
if(blah blah blah){
isError=false;
break;
```

and before the next loop block i simply override the isError

```
isError=true;
//next block of code
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that you say to java do something if value 1 is true or value2 is true or value3 is true,and then you say on the else to do the same if using or.You got to understand that you need to use and && in order to help java to understand the else parameter.

Comment: i'm not following. please elaborate. also it's jumping to the nested else statement within the try-catch loop.

Comment: lets say that "Increasing" is true and all the others are false.Java will first enter the if after doing the if,it will move to else and the you say if "Decreasing" is false(that it is false on if)then it will do something else.You use else when your statement on if is false

Comment: your missing the issue. we know that the compiler is skipping a large block of code and going to the else clause that prints out "...  but starting point value must be smaller than ending point value!..." seeing how i have placeholder for the value tested in the if statement that should be true but is supposed to be overridden in the previous line, for some reason the compiler is skipping  the user assignment and if block and going only to the else, regardless of what the value is.